# Qt Creator -- how do I set the model of a QTreeView inside the Designer?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm learning [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29) independently, and this may seem like an easy question (because it is).  I primarily come from a [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) background, so the concepts are very similar.

My question:

I am using Qt Designer to create a QTreeView item in the UI Designer.  How do I do something as simple as setting the model of the TreeView?

Usually I would do something like:

```
QTreeView *tree = new QTreeView();
tree->setModel( &myModel);
```

I don't even know how to get a reference to the QTreeView object that the UI Designer created.  Any direction will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your version of Qt, your main window will either include as a member or privately inherit a class with all of your designer widgets.  So, within MainWindow, e.g. either my_widget->show(); or ui->my_widget->show(); to show the widget, respectively.

In your case, my_tree_view->setModel(my_model);

Comment: EDIT:  It looks like my QTreeView is under the UI Widget: centralWidget.  The problem is, I can't seem to get a reference to the QTreeview using ui->centralWidget->myTreeView .  It doesn't exist.

Comment: Try rebuilding, you should be able to see it.  I can see View objects I've created in Designer this way.  Are you using QtCreator or QtDesigner on its own?

Comment: I'm using QTCreator. Is there a difference?

Comment: If you were using QtDesigner on its own somehow that could explain a failure of designer widgets to properly integrate into your code, but anyway, on the basis of your edit, presumably myTreeView *is* the centralWidget.  Have you run ui->setupUi(this); within the ctor?  That could also be a problem, you should be able to see ui->myTreeView.